# How does RewriteBase work in .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have seen this in a few `.htaccess` examples

```
RewriteBase /
```

It appears to be somewhat similar in functionality to the `<base href="">` of HTML.

I believe it may automatically prepend its value to the beginning of `RewriteRule` statements (possibly ones without a leading slash)?

I could not get it to work properly. I think it's use could come in very handy for site portability, as I often have a development server which is different to a production one. My current method leaves me deleting portions out of my `RewriteRule` statements.

Can anyone explain to me briefly how to implement it?

Thanks

Comment: Manual: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritebase

Comment: RewriteBase only works in the directory or .htaccess context ... refer to context for the link @SalmanPK provided.

Comment: See this answer for a good description. http://stackoverflow.com/a/2137593/292060

Comment: This is a more in-depth answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21348047/632951

Comment: This is a 1-line answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46541685/632951

Comment: How RewriteBase directive works https://amitoverflow.com/2020/12/06/how-rewritebase-works-with-rewriterule-in-an-htaccess-file/

Answer (score 110, accepted):

In my own words, after reading the docs and experimenting:

You can use `RewriteBase` to provide a *base* for your rewrites. Consider this

```
# invoke rewrite engine
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /~new/

# add trailing slash if missing
    rewriteRule ^(([a-z0-9\-]+/)*[a-z0-9\-]+)$ $1/ [NC,R=301,L]
```

This is a real rule I used to ensure that URLs have a trailing slash.  This will convert

```
http://www.example.com/~new/page
```

to

```
http://www.example.com/~new/page/
```

By having the `RewriteBase` there, you make the relative path come off the `RewriteBase` parameter.

Comment: “come off the RewriteBase parameter” - did you mean the rewriteRule parameter? :)

Comment: I want to clear up some details on htaccess.. does a ReWriteBase set it for all rules in the htaccess *following* what its declaration? is there a way to unset it, can it be reset?

Comment: @Kissaki: No, the `$1` matches the parenthesised RewriteRule pattern, but the relative path for the substitution comes off the RewriteBase parameter. So, the resulting substitution is `/~new/$1/`.

Comment: @Damon: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2434820/many-rewritebase-in-one-htaccess-file) regarding multiple `RewriteBase` directives. In short, you can't have more than one - I think the _last_ `RewriteBase` directive wins, and affects the whole .htaccess file.

Comment: -1; this answer seems to have helped others, but is totally opaque to me. I could've guessed that *"You can use `RewriteBase` to provide a base for your rewrites"* - that's pretty much just a rearrangement of the words - but I have no idea what a "base" *is* in this context, nor how the meaning of the example you've given would differ if the `RewriteBase` line were removed. Off to the manual I go...

Comment: @MarkAmery If you discovered a clearer description, please edit this answer.

Comment: Slightly unrelated, but holy war time.. ;)  Rewrite the other way around, remove trailing slash (or at least check for periods) - or you could end up with URLs looking like `/webshop/rewrittenProductUrl.html/`

Comment: @alex I'm sorry, your answer is highly voted and accepted, but it totally fails to explain what `RewriteBase` actually does. Other answers like those from rjmunro and community wiki do a better job.

Comment: what if i want to do the reverse, get rid of or rather hide a subdirectory which holds all the files??

Answer (score 116):

`RewriteBase` is only applied to the ***target*** of a ***relative*** rewrite rule.

- Using RewriteBase like this...

  ```
  RewriteBase /folder/
  RewriteRule a\.html b.html
  ```
- is essentially the same as...

  ```
  RewriteRule a\.html /folder/b.html
  ```
- But when the .htaccess file is inside `/folder/` then this also points to the same target:

  ```
  RewriteRule a\.html b.html
  ```

Although the docs imply always using a `RewriteBase`, Apache usually detects it correctly for paths under the DocumentRoot unless:

- You are using `Alias` directives
- You are using .htaccess rewrite rules to perform *HTTP redirects* (rather than just silent rewriting) to *relative URLs*

In these cases, you may find that you need to specify the RewriteBase.

However, since it's a confusing directive, it's generally better to simply specify absolute (aka 'root relative') URIs in your rewrite targets.  Other developers reading your rules will grasp these more easily.

---

*Quoting from [Jon Lin's excellent in-depth answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21348047/195835):*

In an htaccess file, mod_rewrite works similar to a `<Directory>` or `<Location>` container. and the [`RewriteBase`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritebase) is used to provide a relative path base.

For example, say you have this folder structure:

```
DocumentRoot
|-- subdir1
`-- subdir2
    `-- subsubdir
```

So you can access:

- `http://example.com/`  (root)
- `http://example.com/subdir1`  (subdir1)
- `http://example.com/subdir2`  (subdir2)
- `http://example.com/subdir2/subsubdir`  (subsubdir)

The URI that gets sent through a `RewriteRule` is relative to the directory containing the htaccess file. So if you have:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ -
```

- In the root htaccess, and the request is `/a/b/c/d`, then the captured URI (`$1`) is `a/b/c/d`.
- If the rule is in `subdir2` and the request is `/subdir2/e/f/g` then the captured URI is `e/f/g`.
- If the rule is in the `subsubdir`, and the request is `/subdir2/subsubdir/x/y/z`, then the captured URI is `x/y/z`.

**The directory that the rule is in has that part stripped off of the URI. The rewrite base has no affect on this, this is simply how per-directory works.**

What the rewrite base *does* do, is provide a URL-path base (*not* a file-path base) for any relative paths in the **rule's target**. So say you have this rule:

```
RewriteRule ^foo$ bar.php [L]
```

The `bar.php` is a relative path, as opposed to:

```
RewriteRule ^foo$ /bar.php [L]
```

where the `/bar.php` is an absolute path. The absolute path will *always* be the "root" (in the directory structure above). That means that regardless of whether the rule is in the "root", "subdir1", "subsubdir", etc. the `/bar.php` path always maps to `http://example.com/bar.php`.

But the other rule, with the relative path, it's based on the directory that the rule is in. So if

```
RewriteRule ^foo$ bar.php [L]
```

is in the "root" and you go to `http://example.com/foo`, you get served `http://example.com/bar.php`. But if that rule is in the "subdir1" directory, and you go to `http://example.com/subdir1/foo`, you get served `http://example.com/subdir1/bar.php`. etc. This sometimes works and sometimes doesn't, as the documentation says, it's supposed to be *required* for relative paths, but most of the time it seems to work. Except when you are redirecting (using the `R` flag, or implicitly because you have `http://host` in your rule's target). That means this rule:

```
RewriteRule ^foo$ bar.php [L,R]
```

if it's in the "subdir2" directory, and you go to `http://example.com/subdir2/foo`, mod_rewrite will mistake the relative path as a file-path instead of a URL-path and because of the `R` flag, you'll end up getting redirected to something like: `http://example.com/var/www/localhost/htdocs/subdir1`. Which is obviously not what you want.

**This is where `RewriteBase` comes in. The directive tells mod_rewrite what to append to the beginning of every relative path.** So if I have:

```
RewriteBase /blah/
RewriteRule ^foo$ bar.php [L]
```

in "subsubdir", going to `http://example.com/subdir2/subsubdir/foo` will actually serve me `http://example.com/blah/bar.php`. The "bar.php" is added to the end of the base. In practice, this example is usually not what you want, because you can't have multiple bases in the same directory container or htaccess file.

In most cases, it's used like this:

```
RewriteBase /subdir1/
RewriteRule ^foo$ bar.php [L]
```

where those rules would be in the "subdir1" directory and

```
RewriteBase /subdir2/subsubdir/
RewriteRule ^foo$ bar.php [L]
```

would be in the "subsubdir" directory.

This partly allows you to make your rules portable, so you can drop them in any directory and only need to change the base instead of a bunch of rules. For example if you had:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^foo$ /subdir1/bar.php [L]
RewriteRule ^blah1$ /subdir1/blah.php?id=1 [L]
RewriteRule ^blah2$ /subdir1/blah2.php [L]
...
```

such that going to `http://example.com/subdir1/foo` will serve `http://example.com/subdir1/bar.php` etc. And say you decided to move all of those files and rules to the "subsubdir" directory. Instead of changing every instance of `/subdir1/` to `/subdir2/subsubdir/`, you could have just had a base:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /subdir1/
RewriteRule ^foo$ bar.php [L]
RewriteRule ^blah1$ blah.php?id=1 [L]
RewriteRule ^blah2$ blah2.php [L]
...
```

And then when you needed to move those files and the rules to another directory, just change the base:

```
RewriteBase /subdir2/subsubdir/
```

and that's it.

Comment: For me, I missed `RewriteEngine On`. No need on 1and1 for example but it's required on my dedicated server.

Comment: Detailed short answer : how RewriteBase directive works https://amitoverflow.com/2020/12/06/how-rewritebase-works-with-rewriterule-in-an-htaccess-file/

Answer (score 43):

AFAIK, RewriteBase is only used to fix cases where mod_rewrite is running in a `.htaccess` file not at the root of a site and it guesses the wrong web path (as opposed to filesystem path) for the folder it is running in. So if you have a RewriteRule in a .htaccess in a folder that maps to `http://example.com/myfolder` you can use:

```
RewriteBase myfolder
```

If mod_rewrite isn't working correctly.

Trying to use it to achieve something unusual, rather than to fix this problem sounds like a recipe to getting very confused.

Comment: Does it need to end with a trailing slash?

Comment: @self, No. Tested, and sub-explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11443194/632951

Answer (score 25):

RewriteBase is only useful in situations where you can only put a .htaccess at the root of your site. Otherwise, you may be better off placing your different .htaccess files in different directories of your site and completely omitting the RewriteBase directive.

Lately, for complex sites, I've been taking them out, because it makes deploying files from testing to live just one more step complicated.

Comment: Although this may be good advice, this is not an answer to the question at all. It should thus have been a comment to the question, not have received (as many) upvotes and definitely not accepted as “answer”.

Comment: "better off placing your different .htaccess files in different directories" - I'm not sure that this is good advice? Having .htaccess files dotted all over your site can make debugging/maintenance a nightmare. I would have said it was _preferable_ to have one .htaccess file in the root of your site.

Comment: @w3d There's also a timing matter: everytime a subdirectory is accessed, multiple .htaccess files are parsed (from the root to current subdirectory). Having a lot of files could lower the speed of the overall answer to the request, as opposed to a single file in the root, even if it contains a lot of rules..

Answer (score 22):

When I develop, it's on a different domain within a folder.  When I take a site live, that folder doesn't exist anymore.  Using RewriteBase allows me to use the same .htaccess file in both environments.

When live:

```
RewriteBase /
# RewriteBase /dev_folder/
```

When developing:

```
# RewriteBase /
RewriteBase /dev_folder/
```

Comment: I'm sure this will not always work. What if you used `%{REQUEST_URI}` in a `RewriteCond` directive for example?

Comment: @user1669830, If you've got just one rewriterule, you could've just added the base to the rewriterule https://stackoverflow.com/a/46541685/632951

Comment: Or, in most cases, just removing the `RewriteBase` directive altogether would be preferable. Relative substitution strings default to the directory that contains the `.htaccess` file.

Answer (score 18):

The clearest explanation I found was not in the current 2.4 apache docs, but in [version 2.0](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritebase).

```
#  /abc/def/.htaccess -- per-dir config file for directory /abc/def
#  Remember: /abc/def is the physical path of /xyz, i.e., the server
#            has a 'Alias /xyz /abc/def' directive e.g.

RewriteEngine On

#  let the server know that we were reached via /xyz and not
#  via the physical path prefix /abc/def
RewriteBase   /xyz
```

How does it work? For you apache hackers, this 2.0 doc goes on to give "detailed information about the internal processing steps."

Lesson learned: While we need to be familiar with "current," gems can be found in the annals.

Answer (score 6):

This command can explicitly set the base URL for your rewrites. If you wish to start in the root of your domain, you would include the following line before your RewriteRule:

```
RewriteBase /
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe this excerpt from the Apache documentation, complements well the previous answers :

> This directive is required when you use a relative path in a
>   substitution in per-directory (htaccess) context unless either of the
>   following conditions are true:
>
> - The original request, and the substitution, are underneath the DocumentRoot (as opposed to reachable by other means, such as Alias).
> - The filesystem path to the directory containing the RewriteRule, suffixed by the relative substitution is also valid as a URL path on
>     the server (this is rare).
>
> As previously mentioned, in other contexts, it is only useful to make
>   your rule shorter. Moreover, also as previously mentioned, you can
>   achieve the same thing by placing the htaccess file in the
>   subdirectory.

Answer (score -4):

I simply delete .htaccess file and it runs perfectly