# WAMP Apache rewrite issue in .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, wamp

I am working in a WAMP environment trying to create a bare bones front controller and have started with creating an .htaccess file in my project root (i.e. www/molecule/ The .htaccess contains:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
IndexIgnore */*
# Turn on the RewriteEngine
RewriteEngine On
#  Rules
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php
```

Apache rewrite_module is enabled in my WAMP settings, and also uncommented in the httpd.conf, but getting an Internal Server Error when I try to load any pages with that .htaccess in the directory. The Apache Error log reads:

```
[alert] [client 127.0.0.1] C:/wamp/www/molecule/.htaccess: Invalid command 'RewriteEngine', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
```

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Update your question with your folder structure. You're saying your .htaccess file is in the root of your server "www/front_controller_test", but the error message you're giving is referring to "C:/wamp/www/molecule/". What's your root folder and where is the .htaccess file?

Comment: Right, Thx. It was molecule. the folder structure is www/molecule/index.php & www/molecule/.htaccess

Comment: And is the "root" of your web server (or virtual host) pointing to that folder so that http://localhost will look in that folder, or do you have to enter http://localhost/molecule ? There seems to be some debate whether you need to add [RewriteBase](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2137492/why-is-rewritebase-neccesary-when-rewriting-url-via-htaccess) or not. Also, I have to ask this...have you restarted your server?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks like you didn't turn on your mod_rewrite module. Find your httpd.conf file and do a search for `mod_rewrite`, the line should look something like this:

```
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
```

Make sure you uncomment that by removing the `#` in front of it.

Comment: Using WAMP, you can even easily do it through the GUI. Just left click the WAMP trayicon, go to "Apache" and then "Apache modules" and select "rewrite module"

Comment: I don't think I was clear enough in my post but I DID have the rewrite_module enabled, both in the WAMP system tray and in the httpd.conf itself.

Comment: Do you have `AllowOverride None` set for the directory your htaccess file is in?

Comment: Jon - I did not - I only had the exact syntax at the beginning of my post. But somehow it started working at some point and I'm not exactly sure where. I do know I had the rewrite_module enabled from the beginning but the pages in that dir weren't displaying in the beginning. Since I just started working with Apache settings, I asked the question but it looks like I had it close to right from the start. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

if it is related to hosting site then ask to your hosting company or if you want to enable it in wamp local machine then check this youtube step by step tutorial related to enabling rewrite module in wamp apache 
https://youtu.be/xIspOX9FuVU?t=1m43s 
Wamp server icon -> Apache -> Apache Modules and check the rewrite module option
it should be checked but after that restart all services in wamp