# Problem with .htaccess (mod_rewrite). RewriteRule's doens't work correctly

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a problem with my two RewriteRules.

.htaccess:

```
# protect the htaccess file
<files .htaccess>
 order allow,deny
 deny from all
</files>

RewriteEngine On
Options +FollowSymlinks
Options -Indexes
RewriteBase /test/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^download/([0-9]+)$ download.php?id=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?c=view&misc=$1 [B]
```

If the url contains download (some like this: mydomain.com/download/9) the first rule should redict this request to download.php?id=9. But it doesn't.

var_dump($_GET) shows the following:

```
array(2) { ["c"]=>  string(4) "view" ["misc"]=>  string(9) "index.php" } index.php
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I solved the problem.

```
# protect the htaccess file
<files .htaccess>
 order allow,deny
 deny from all
</files>

RewriteEngine On
Options +FollowSymlinks
Options -Indexes

RewriteBase /test/download/
RewriteRule ^download/([0-9]+)$ download.php?id=$1 [L]

RewriteBase /test/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?c=view&misc=$1 [B]
```

Thanks guys! :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not with the rule. It works here.

http://wingsoflol.org/download/9

My download.php contains

```
Hi!
<br>Id = <?
echo $_GET['id'];
?>
```

and the rule is

`RewriteRule ^download/([0-9]+)$ download.php?id=$1 [L]`

Are you sure the RewriteBase should be /test/ ?

Comment: Yes. I'm working at localhost and the folder test:
http://localhost/test/download/9

But add the second rule and try again.

Comment: Works perfectly here. Try adding the prefix test/ to the rules and see if this is the problem. For fun, I added the RewriteBase rule, and it does not work here. Read  http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritebase

Comment: Also read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/704102/how-does-rewritebase-work-in-htaccess