# Install WordPress in its own directory but permalink fails

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, amazon-ec2, url-rewriting, permalinks

I installed WordPress on EC2, located in `/var/www/html/wordpress`. I followed the WordPress guide to copy index.php and .htaccess to root which is `/var/www/html`, and modified index.php and setting in admin panel. It works pretty well if I stick to only default link, such as: `http://www.cubcanfly.com/?p=5`, however other permalink options fails, actually all of the permalink options.

My **.htaccess** is

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

in **/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf**

```
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
```

is NOT commented.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Finally I find the problem. It's the AllowOverride option in httpd.conf which is located in /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf, "sudo find / -name httpd.conf -print" can easily find it.
I changed any AllowOverride NONE->ALL where i can find in the file. It just worked,even without doing any change to .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

This .htaccess works on my host in which wordpress is installed in its own directory.

Thank you @adlawson @Will, without you, I couldn't find the problem.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks  this official guide is quite enough to use permalink even wordpress is installed in a sub directory.

Answer (score 4):

Have a look at this post [How does RewriteBase work in .htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/704102/how-does-rewritebase-work-in-htaccess)

You need to change `RewriteBase /` to `RewriteBase /wordpress`

Comment: And don't forget to change the last RewriteRule to /wordpress/index.php.

Comment: @adlawson @Will I changed .htaccess to ... RewriteBase /wordpress...RewriteRule . /wordpress/index.php [L] and permalink still doesn't work, thanks for you help.

Comment: @adlawson @Will thank you for your help, I finally find what going on here. I didn't enable AllowOverride in httpd.conf. Once i set it to All, it works pretty well with the .htaccess file I posted in the main thread.We don't actually need to do anything ^_^ cheers.

Answer (score 0):

I did not need to edit RewriteBase in .htaccess.
The problem really is in httpd configuration for EC2 machines.

My .htaccess -

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

In /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf -

```
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>

# AllowOverride controls what directives may be placed in .htaccess files.
# It can be "All", "None", or any combination of the keywords:
#   Options FileInfo AuthConfig Limit
#
AllowOverride All
```