# Wordpress permalinks not working - htaccess and module rewrite enabled

Tags: wordpress, apache

I've set permalinks to /%postname%/, and have updated .htaccess in the root directory. The module rewrite is enabled on my machine (localhost). I can't think of any other reason why it's not working. Can anyone help me debug it?

Here's the logged error:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [22/Jan/2014:10:27:57 +0000] "GET /olp/about/ HTTP/1.1" 404 497 "http://localhost/olp/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/30.0.1599.66 Safari/537.36"
```

Edit:

.htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /olp/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /olp/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

WP is installed in localhost/olp, and .htaccess is in that same directory.

Edit: more info. In my apache2.conf, I've got:

```
<Directory "/var/www/"> 
Options FollowSymLinks 
AllowOverride All 
Order allow,deny 
Allow from all 
</Directory>
```

Is this configuration correct?

Comment: "and have updated .htaccess in the root directory"... Post the code! Also make it clear - where is your WP installed (in a subdirectory?) and where is the .htaccess placed (the path to it).

Comment: Thanks for the response, I've added the relevant code.

Comment: Have you tried saving your permalinks again. Sometimes it solves the problem.

Comment: Just tried that, but the problem persists.

Answer (score 3):

This is now solved.

Although in apache.conf, I have AllowOverride All, this wasn't set in /etc/apache2/sites-available/default. There it had AllowOverride None. So I just changed this, restarted apache and now it works.

Comment: Glad it's resolved! So you just enabled the .htaccess override from the specified file and it works now with the .htaccess contents you posted, could you please confirm, thanks?

Comment: I had the opposite problem where it was 'AllowOverride All' in 'sites-available' but was set to 'None' in 'apache2.conf'

Answer (score 0):

You may need to copy the index.php (or you may first try to skip this one) and the .htaccess from /localhost/olp to /localhost/ dir.

This advice is according the docs at: http://codex.wordpress.org/Giving_WordPress_Its_Own_Directory

Usually it is needed when you install it in /localhost and move it to /localhost/olp. But I'm not experienced in installing WP in a subdirectory.

Another similar questions are available:

- [Install WordPress in its own directory but permalink fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6715609/install-wordpress-in-its-own-directory-but-permalink-fails)
- https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/67332/permalink-issues-by-installing-wordpress-in-subdirectory-subfolder

Make sure your .htaccess works!

And a final tip - as it is a localhost installation, you probably can install it directly in the main document root (then I can help much more).

Comment: I can't copy index.php and .htaccess to the www root directory because I've got several installs, all under that root.

Comment: If you are sure your .htaccess works, then you should at least test something, but the first one is to make sure your .htaccess from /localhost/olp is working!

Comment: Ask google: how to test .htaccess is working (also check your OS - Win/Linux/Mac... your web server - apache, nginx...)

Comment: This didn't work for me. It also seems like moving `.htaccess` and `index.php` into the parent directory defeats the purpose of keeping the project in a subdirectory, or at least my purpose, which is to be able to switch among multiple WP projects.

Answer (score 0):

Try to clear-up your .htaccess file and than save permalinks again in wp-admin, wordpress will add Rewrite to .htaccess, sometimes it's helping.