# .htaccess rewrite specifics

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

at the moment I've got the following code:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

What this code does is allow users to go to /pagename instead of /pagename.php

Is there a way to make it so this only works for a specific page because at the moment this code makes this sitewide?

Answer (score 0):

add a new RewriteCond after the two rewriteCond and check if the request is for the specific page.

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(myPage)/

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html

you can also use the RewriteBase directive.

Example
[How does RewriteBase work in .htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/704102/how-does-rewritebase-work-in-htaccess)