# Deploying CakePHP without document root?

Tags: cakephp

I'm currently in the investigation stage of using CakePHP (2.x in particular). I noticed that on the [deployment docs](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/deployment.html#set-document-root) I need to set the document root accordingly in httpd.conf, unfortunately for this project I don't have access to httpd.conf nor any directories below the given webroot.

Given that, my two questions are:
1. Is it possible to still run CakePHP without being able to set the document root?
2. Are there any potential downsides in doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Absolutely, you can use CakePHP in any subdirectory. The only thing you may find useful is the RewriteBase directive, which I think is well explained here: [How does RewriteBase work in .htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/704102/how-does-rewritebase-work-in-htaccess)

The one other small problem I've noted is that some CakePHP plugins out there do assume a root directory :( which is unfortunate, and I've had to append Router::url("/") when I see those.

Other than that, you should have no problem running CakePHP on a subdirectory.