# Codeigniter Page Not Found , change in .htacess

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite, http-status-code-404

I was working on my test live server ,  i made some changes in a file and saved it , suddenly the whole website crashed.

When i now log to my test server(http://www.uplits.com/). It shows a Directory has no index file error and when i log into the codeigniter(http://uplits.com/skidt/admin919/codeigniter/)

It shows a page not found error.

Please help , i dont know what could have gone wrong.

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt) 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Please read the FAQ. How about showing us your current .htaccess file? Or perhaps you should revert to the old version.

Comment: I did try to undo the changes but wouldn't work.

This is  my current .htacess file

RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?$1 [L,QSA] 


anything else i need to show?

Comment: Rewrite base problem? see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/704102/how-does-rewritebase-work-in-htaccess , try setting rewritebase. And also, an error log might help you too. see if you can find one.

Answer (score 0):

Remove:

```
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
```

You shouldn't need this as the !-f & !-d conditions should take care of this.

Comment: I did the change , it still isnt working .

Anything else that would be required?

Comment: Please HELP guys.

The whole domain isnt working , I cant access any folder on the browser.