# Why won't this mod_rewrite rule work with CodeIgniter?

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite

```
RewriteRule ^(new-york/new-york-city/chelsea/10001) index.php [L]
```

The above code does not work. It gives me a 404 error in Codeigniter. However, the following code does work.

```
RewriteRule ^(new-york/new-york-city/chelsea/10001) http://anywebsitehere.com/ [L]
```

Comment: Where is your .htaccess file located?  If it's in a weird location... you might want to consider using [RewriteBase](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/704102/how-does-rewritebase-work-in-htaccess).

Comment: The .htaccess file is located in the main directory.

Comment: Also doesn't work. It keeps trying to load a page called new-york via CodeIgniter pattern of controller/action and giving me a 404.

Comment: Actually, why is it that you are using a rewrite rule like this? :)

Comment: We're working with a marketing guy and he wants pretty URLs. Basically, he wants (new-york/new-york-city/chelsea/10001) to load a page full of listings/places that are in New York. So the easiest way is to use our existing Search functionality which leaves an ugly url such as search/param1=ASD&param2=ASDF.

Comment: Ah; if that's the case... would you want to make the rewrite rule a bit more flexible (or dynamic)?

Comment: For now, I want to handcode everything. This is a script we bought off the internet and it's full of bugs and glitches. The idea is to get some users on it and then eventually build our own system.

Comment: You should use a standard CI .htaccess file, and use routes to catch these.

Comment: @Cryode I actually went that route and was told to use a .htaccess file. Check my profile history.

Comment: Yeah, @Cyrode is correct, you should be using routes for this.

Answer (score 0):

The `RewriteRule` just rewrites to `index.php`, which calls the default route, if you have one setup. If you want to go to your search, you must rewrite to the search controller and method and pass the pretty URL or part of it as arguments

```
RewriteRule ^new-york/new-york-city/chelsea/10001 index.php/search_controller/search_method/$0 [L]
```

This will call in `application/controllers/search_controller.php` the method `search_method` with the pretty URL as arguments

```
search_method('new-york', 'new-york-city', 'chelsea', '10001');
```