# How do I re-write this htaccess file?

Tags: php, .htaccess

I got this from this page: https://developers.google.com/commerce/wallet/online/quickstart-php

I am wondering how to re-write it to work in a subdirectory.

like /subdirectory/index.php

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L,NC,QSA]
```

Comment: Put it in the subdirectory :)

Comment: Study the [mod_rewrite manual](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html) and specifically read up on [what RewriteBase does](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/704102/how-does-rewritebase-work-in-htaccess).

Answer (score 1):

Here's what you need to do:

1. Change the `RewriteBase` to the name of your subdirectory
2. Remove the leading slash from the `/index.php`
3. Place the rules in an htaccess file in your subdirectory.

So say your subdirectory is called `/subdir` and you have `http://domain.com/subdir/index.php`, you'd have this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /subdir/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php [L,NC,QSA]
```