# Htaccess file no longer working when moved from web root to folder

Tags: .htaccess

The following in my htacess file works to remove add a # character to the url. So mysite.com/page2 becomes mysite.com/#page2

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ /#$1 [L,NE,R]
```

This works fine however my site is actually going to be in a folder in the web root, not the root itself. So I need  something like existingsite.com/mysite/page2 to redirect to existingsite.com/mysite/#page2

Ideally I would like to have this controlled by the htaccess thats within my site folder so that I dont need to change the htaccess file for the main site. Ive moved the site (including the htaccess file) into a folder in the web root but now its not working like before (when it was in the web root).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use rewritebase:

`RewriteBase /mysite/`

And your existing rewrites:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /mysite/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ /#$1 [L,NE,R]
```

Also see: [How does RewriteBase work in .htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/704102/how-does-rewritebase-work-in-htaccess)

Comment: It doenst seem to work. Locally my path is http://localhost:8888/site7/one so ive used RewriteBase /site7/

Comment: Ive also tested at mytestingserver.com/site7 which also doesn't work.

Comment: Can you confirm that the htaccess file should be in folder of the new site not the web root?

Comment: It should be in the folder. I did not test this out, but documentation and examples both show this is thé solution.

Answer (score 0):

This works when placed in the htaccess file in the folder of the new site (not the web root).

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ /santa7/#$1 [L,NE,R]
```

Comment: Just `RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ #$1 [L,NE,R]` is better since that will not require change between your localhost and server.