# Modify friendly URLs generated by default in Wordpress (via .htaccess)

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, friendly-url

I have a website done in Wordpress and I need to make some changes in the fiendly URLs.

I’ve created a page from the admin panel named `detail`, this page reads the template file `detail.php` from the templates folder.

The URL that is currently mounted is `http://www.domain.com/detail/1234/` and I need that it could be accessed as `http://www.domain.com/anything/1234/`.

The following lines have been generated by Wordpress but I don’t understand them and I don’t know how to modify them for my purpose:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: So you want to redirect `/anythinghere/1234` to `/detail/1234`?

Comment: You realize that all other sub-pages on your site will break if you do this? domain.com/anything/1234 to domain.com/detail/1234? Since all pages will redirect? Also if you are simply trying to beautify your URL there are alot of lightweight/useful plugins for doing that which will do this for you.

Comment: it's possible to make a rule just for this page? there are other pages but none hangs of this

Comment: @anubhava which url would result from this redirection? how should I do this?

Comment: Actually this is WP page and I won't recommend messing up rewrite rules since WP is very rigid about the permalink structure you provide in WP settings.

Comment: and do something like www.domain.com/detail/1234/anything ?

Comment: You most likely have to adjust Wordpress settings, and I am not familiar with them. The rule you show internally rewrites every request on the server to the index.php page, who handles the request further.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you should really understand what those rules are doing and what you really want to achieve. Then you can try to change the system to fit your needs.

[`IfModule`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#ifmodule) ensures everything inside is processed only when [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) Apache module is present. All the other directives are from this module.

1. `RewriteEngine On` enables URL rewriting.
2. `RewriteBase /` tells the engine that the rules operate inside root. See also the general question on [how `RewriteBase` works](https://stackoverflow.com/q/704102/2157640).
3. `RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]` means that no more rules should be processed (`[L]`) if the current URL to be rewritten is `index.php`. No rewrite takes place. `RewriteRule` directive accepts a [regex](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/glossary.html#regex). See also [regex](/questions/tagged/regex) tag here on SO.
4. All `RewriteCond` directives apply to the following `RewriteRule`. Unless `[OR]` flag is added, they must be all satisfied at the same time to execute the rule. In this case they mean:

   - Requested resource is not a regular file.
   - Requested resource is not a directory.
5. Rewrite any (at least one character long) URL to `index.php`. This is the last (`[L]`) rule to be processed.

When adding new `RewriteRule`s, you probably want to use the WordPress way of doing this, as described in [Zac’s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20626162/2157640). Figuring out the right rule by analogy to the many examples in the manual or here on SO should not be hard.

Answer (score 2):

Put into functions.php maybe a better idea:

functions.php

```
function setRewriteRule($orgRules){
    return array( '/([^/]+)/([0-9]+)/?' => 'index.php?post=$matches[1]' ) + $orgRules;
}

add_filter('rewrite_rules_array', 'setRewriteRule');
```

Then you just need flush the rewrite rules, I usually use 'rewrite-rules-inspector' plugin.

Comment: If you use functions.php make sure your theme is a child theme or it will get wiped out on theme update.

Answer (score 2):

This should solve your problem give it a try ... you can write your own custom permalink without adding any code also if someone tries to access the page via old URL they will be redirected to the new one.

[WordPress Custom Permalinks](http://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-permalinks/)

After installing this you just have to go into pages and type your own URL below the heading