# .htaccess mod_rewrite giving 500 error

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have an .htaccess file that has been working perfectly. However, I just moved the website to a shared host and everything stopped working.

Here is my .htacces:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/preview/([^/]+)/?$ preview.php?c=$1&m=$2&i=$3 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/page/([^/]+)/?$ index.php?c=$1&m=$2&p=$3 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ index.php?c=$1&m=$2 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ index.php?c=$1 [L]
```

I can't be sure but I think the problem is that hosting account is not at the root level. Meaning I have one domain pointing to my hosting account, but then this domain `www.website.com` is pointing to the `/website` folder on the hosting account.

The error message is just:

```
Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator and inform them of the time the error occurred, and the actions you performed just before this error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.

Apache Server at crstrains.com Port 80
```

And there is nothing generated in the error logs.

I expect www.website.com/Policies to equal www.website.com/index.php?c=Policies, and it used to. Not anymore. How can I fix this?

Comment: Have you tried adding a `RewriteBase /website/` right after the `RewriteEngine on` statement. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/704102/how-does-rewritebase-work-in-htaccess

Comment: @KristerAndersson I hadn't tried that but it doesn't seem to help. I did try modifying the number of `/([^/]+)`s and got it to throw a 404 instead, saying that /website/website/index.php cannot be found...

Comment: @Prix As I said in my question, there is nothing generated in the error logs.

Comment: @KristerAndersson Actually, turns out `RewriteBase /` was all I needed, that did the trick.

Comment: @sharf - I add the comment as an short answer =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you try to add
`RewriteBase /`
exactly below
`RewriteEngine On`

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried adding a `RewriteBase /website/` directive after your `RewriteEngine on` statement?

Checkout [How does rewritebase work in .htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/704102/how-does-rewritebase-work-in-htaccess) for more information about how to use `RewriteBase`.

Comment: +1 You did head me in the rigth direction, but Dipak's answer is technically correct for me and got in just before yours.