# What kind of server configuration is needed to have a laravel app working

Tags: laravel, hosting

Using cpanel I have upload into a server a laravel application. During the development I have used MAMP and it works fine.

When I upload the application into my host server, I only can see the first page:

```
http://myurl.com/appname/public/
```

When I try to navigate I always get this error:

```
Not Found

The requested URL /myurl.com/appname/public/account/sign-in was not found on this server.
```

What is the problem? Are there any special configuration for laravel applications?

**Edit:**
.htaccess file content:

```
Options -Indexes
SetEnv DEFAULT_PHP_VERSION 55
```

I tried to add `RewriteBase /`like this:

```
Options -Indexes
SetEnv DEFAULT_PHP_VERSION 55
RewriteBase /
```

But it didn't work either.

I'm using this host https://www.ecowebhosting.co.uk/?page=webhosting&tab=advanced

Comment: This might help http://arbitraryknowledge.com/web-development/laravel/installing-laravel-and-composer-on-a-cpanel-server/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't mention which web server you're using, but if it's apache, it looks like you need to either

1. Tell Apache to process `.htaccess` files (so it can see the rewrite rules that pass everything to index.php
2. Turn on the `mod_rewrite` module, which is the module that does the work of rewriting URLs

When you request a URL like

```
http://example.com/appname/public/account/sign-in
```

in a Laravel application, the rewrite rules turn that in

```
http://example.com/appname/public/index.php/account/sign-in
```

Behind the scenes.  It looks like your server isn't setup to do this.  Also, since you're serving Laravel out of a non root folder, you may need to set the [RewriteBase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/704102/how-does-rewritebase-work-in-htaccess).  However, generally speaking, the ideal Laravel setup is one where the `public` folder is your web root.  If possible, I'd configure your server so that's true as well.

Comment: It is possible to make this configurations through cpanel?