# Subfolders in a REST API

Tags: php, api, rest, mod-rewrite, directory-structure

Let’s say I have a structure like this `https://domain.com/api/rest/v1.0/`, but in the folder `v1.0` I have subfolders like `data-model` and `constants`.

Now let’s say I’m using mod rewrite, so all URLs that have the base URL `https://domain.com/api/rest/v1.0/` get forwarded to `https://domain.com/api/rest/v1.0/index.php`.

Would this affect my PHP files contained in `https://domain.com/api/rest/v1.0/data-model/` and `https://domain.com/api/rest/v1.0/constants/`?

For example, if in `https://domain.com/api/rest/v1.0/index.php` I try to add a file from `https://domain.com/api/rest/v1.0/constants/` using `require_once`, would that cause some kind of redirect loop?

I’m not getting any output after the lines of code where I do the above, but am before. Similarly I’m not getting any errors/reloading of the page in the browser so am at a bit of a loss.

If this is the issue, does anyone have any pointers to a better REST file structure than just lumping all the files in the root folder?

Thanks

**UPDATE**

Here is my rewrite rule:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

    RewriteRule api/rest/v1.0/(.*)$ api/rest/v1.0/index.php?request=$1 [QSA,NC,L]

</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

No, neither your php files nor your directories are affected. mod_rewrite only rewrites URLs. That means that urls are only rewritten if accessed via http request (e.g. with a browser).

Probably your rewrite rules are wrong. Also check php log files for errors.
What are your rules like?

Comment: I thought this too, but as there are no PHP errors included I can’t seem to find the problem. Any suggestions what might be wrong?

Comment: Probably your rewrite rules are wrong. Which ones are they?

Comment: Sure, i’ll find the rules and update as soon as i can

Comment: Try adding `RewriteBase /` after `RewriteEngine On`. See [how-does-rewritebase-work-in-htaccess](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/704102/how-does-rewritebase-work-in-htaccess) for more information.

Comment: Still no output after `require_once`

Comment: Just added an echo at the top of the included file and it was output, there must be an error with the files being included. I’ll comb through each and reply

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the solution was that my subdirectories weren’t properly added in `require_once` as my paths were relative. So instead of `require_once 'folder/file.php'` I changed my files so they now read `require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/folder/file.php'`