# Rewrite trailing slash everywhere

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am having problems with my `.htaccess` file.
It looks like this:

```
RewriteEngine On  

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^website\.de [NC]  
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.website.de/folder/$1 [L,R=301]  

RewriteRule ^traffic/?$ traffic.php [NC,L]  
RewriteRule ^what-if/?$ whatif.php [NC,L]
```

If I call `www.website.de/folder/traffic` I get `www.website.de/folder/traffic/`.
But if I call `www.website.de/folder/what-if` the trailing `/` is missing.

**How can I add it everywhere?**

Comment: `traffic` seems to be an existing folder (that's why you get a trailing slash) but `what-if` does not exist. Also, i don't see any reference to a subfolder `folder` in your htaccess code, is it your entire code ?

Comment: no traffic folder - thats all in my .htaccess

Comment: Where is your htaccess located ? In document root folder or in `folder` subfolder ?

Comment: in the subfolder but whole side "runs" in that subfolder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to specify a `RewriteBase` since your htaccess is in a subfolder.
Also, you have to disable `MultiViews` option to avoid the problem you have.

```
Options -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /folder/

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^website\.de$ [NC]  
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.website.de/folder/$1 [L,R=301] 

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ $1/ [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^traffic/$ traffic.php [NC,L]  
RewriteRule ^what-if/$ whatif.php [NC,L]
```

Comment: Thank you for your effort! Didn't work that way but pointed me to [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/704102/how-does-rewritebase-work-in-htaccess) this earlier question. Now i added this line `rewriteRule ^(([a-z0-9\-]+/)*[a-z0-9\-]+)$ $1/ [NC,R=301,L]` and this helped. could you maybe edit your answer and I will be happy to accept :)

Comment: Well what you asked was how to get `http://domain.com/folder/traffic` (without a trailing slash, just as `what-if` right ?). Because if you're now adding trailing slash, you have to add something in my code

Comment: I seemed to wrote it unclear. I wanted to have the trailing slash (think it looks neat). I edited my question.

Comment: No problem, my bad. You can see my edited answer which takes your comment into consideration