# .htaccess -> index.php in web folder (url has to be web/)

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm having problems setting up my *.htaccess* file. In my **web** folder (in the **root** of my project) I have *index.php* . Now I have to go to **mydomain.com/web/** to see my index.php .

I've added a .htacces file in my **/web** folder but it isn't working. This is the content of my .htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine On

   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have 2 .htaccess for this:

**root .htaccess (a level above web):**

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^((?!web/).*)$ web/$1 [NC,L]
```

**/web/.htaccess:**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /web/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.*) index.php [L]
```

Comment: That gave me the error : You don't have permission to access / on this server.

Comment: Can you check your actual `DocumentRoot` from Apache config?

Comment: How can I check this? Tried to find /etc/apache2/conf/httpd.conf but httpd.conf wasn't there.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `RewriteBase` ?

```
RewriteBase /web/
```

This post can be also helpful

- [How does RewriteBase work in .htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/704102/how-does-rewritebase-work-in-htaccess)

Comment: Tried to add it but same result

Comment: @nielsv, what if you try smth like this `RewriteRule ^([^?]*)$ index.php?path=$1 [NC,L,QSA]`. `.htaccess` should be in folder where `index.php` locates. Or `RewriteRule ^([^?]*)$ /web/index.php?path=$1 [NC,L,QSA]` if `.htaccess` location is *root*.