# Deploy Flask app with FastCGI, unexpected application root

Tags: apache, flask, fastcgi, bluehost

I deployed my website made with flask to bluehost following the tutorial [here](http://willhaley.com/blog/flask-on-bluehost/). Namely I used apache and fastcgi. In the my application.fcgi file, I have:

```
#! /home2/wandonye/python/python34/envs/flask/bin/python
project = "vshare"

from flup.server.fcgi import WSGIServer
from vshare import create_app
application = create_app()

WSGIServer(application).run()
```

But then every link generated by url_for has an extra myapplication.fcgi in it. So instead of having "www.mydomain.com/signin" I got "www.mydomain.com/myapplication.fcgi/signin".

Feels like my PROJECT_ROOT is changed.

I used to deploy the website on my own computer with apache+uWSGI without any problem.

Is there anything special about fastcgi I should keep in mind? How can I remove the unwanted "myapplication.fcgi" in my links.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I eventually find a solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29990981/flask-function-url-for-doesnt-work-for-sub-domain-deployment-on-bluehost/29997366#29997366)

The problem is essential to fcgi, not about apache setup. So the only way to work around it is to change the string coming from url_for, delete the unwanted “xxx.fcgi”