# Wamp and flightphp not working together

Tags: php, wamp, flightphp

This is my repository on [github](https://github.com/LazarRistic/PS-PKCalypso).

When i go on `http://localhost:port/PS-PKCalypso/rest/` - i get my `hello nestos!`

But, when i go to `http://localhost:port/PS-PKCalypso/rest/sada` - i get `404 not found` error.

On my wamp i have changed AllowOverride to All, enable rewrite_model, php_curl...

P.S On my friends xampp it works great.

Any one with idea or solution? tnx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where is the **/sada** route in the **rest/index.php** ?
You must define it.

OR, You did it and problem is continue: You can solve this problem with .htaccess *RewriteBase*
[How does RewriteBase work in .htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/704102/how-does-rewritebase-work-in-htaccess)