# htaccess to manually redirect to renamed "Main Page"

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, mediawiki

Our site has something like this as our `.htaccess`

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/wiki/Main_Page$ /wiki/Welcome_to_Our_Site [R]
RewriteRule ^/?wiki/?$ / [R]

RewriteRule ^/?$ %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/index.php?title=Welcome_to_Our_Site [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^/?wiki(/.+)$ %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/index.php [L]
RewriteRule ^/?w(/.*)?$ %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/index.php [L]

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} !-f
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} !-d
RewriteRule ^/?images/thumb/[0-9a-f]/[0-9a-f][0-9a-f]/([^/]+)/([0-9]+)px-.*$ %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/thumb.php?f=$1&width=$2 [L,QSA,B]

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} !-f
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} !-d
RewriteRule ^/?images/thumb/archive/[0-9a-f]/[0-9a-f][0-9a-f]/([^/]+)/([0-9]+)px-.*$ %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/thumb.php?f=$1&width=$2&archived=1 [L,QSA,B]
```

I have also used `MediaWiki:Mainpage` to point to `Welcome_to_Our_Site`.

For the sake of users who may have bookmarked the old page, I would also like `Main_Page` to manually redirect to `Welcome_to_Our_Site`--*without a redirect notice*--but it is not happening.

I originally moved the `Main Page` to `Welcome_to_Our_Site`, creating a redirect within the Mediawiki software, but even when I delete the `Main Page` or add text into it without a redirect, my `htaccess` rule does not override Mediawiki's own redirecting as I think it should and redirect `Main Page` to `Welcome_to_Our_Site`, changing the URL, but without the Mediawiki "(Redirected from Main Page)" redirect text showing up. What is wrong with the line I expect should do the trick `RewriteRule ^/wiki/Main_Page$ /wiki/Welcome_to_Our_Site [R]` or the cascading after it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep your first 2 rules as this:

```
RewriteRule ^/?wiki/Main_Page/?$ /wiki/Welcome_to_Our_Site [NC,L,R=302]

RewriteRule ^/?wiki/?$ / [R=302,L,NC]
```

Assuming this htaccess is placed in site root directory and the there is no .htaccess in `/wiki/` directory (if at all that is a directory).

Comment: +1 for cueing me into the need for `/?` at the beginning. However, it seems I did need my old use of `[R]` as `[NC,L]` did not do the trick.

Comment: Yes you can add `R` but then URL in browser will also change to `/wiki/Welcome_to_Our_Site`

Comment: I've updated the OP to clarify I wanted it to change the URL. If you want to edit your answer, I'll put yours as the answer.

Comment: @BrettZamir: You *probably* should add a [RewriteBase](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/704102/how-does-rewritebase-work-in-htaccess) directive to your .htaccess file, and get rid of all the `%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}` hacks. (That said, your entire setup looks a little bit funny, especially the `/w/` redirect. I may write a longer answer about this later, if I have time.)

Comment: And yes `%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/` can be removed from target URIs even without any `RewriteBase` since those are for internal rewrites only.