# Change part of URL subdomain / permalink using .htaccess without causing 404

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm using WordPress and I have a URL like this:

```
domain.com/my-pages/The+Title/go/
```

I want the 'go' removed, and `my-pages` changed to books, like this:

```
domain.com/books/The+Title
```

without causing a 404 error.

It isn't possible via permalinks as I'm using a custom plugin.

I've tried this in `.htaccess` but it doesn't work:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.domain.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^my-pages/([^\.]+)/go/$ books/$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

IIRC when in `.htaccess` the path starts with a slash ("`/`"), so as you anchor the regular expression at the beginning of the string ("`^`" symbol):

```
RewriteRule ^/my-pages/([^\.]+)/go/$ books/$1 [L]
             ^
              `-- missing in your case
```

You can control that with [`RewriteBase`<sup>*Apache DOCs*</sup>](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritebase), see as well:

- [How does RewriteBase work in .htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/q/704102/367456) (Stackoverflow Q&A, Apr 2009)