# Unable to login in Magento Admin

Tags: php, magento, magento2

I just installed magento 2.0.3 on mac . The installation is done with success. My admin address is

```
Magento Admin Address:  http://127.0.0.1/magento3/admin/
```

On click of this link , I am getting `The requested URL /magento3/admin/ was not found on this server.` error.
I have copied pub/.htacess file to magento folder but no luck.
Even the home page i.e. http://127.0.0.1/magento3 is coming with broken **js & css**

Comment: Can you try adding index.php in the url like  http://127.0.0.1/magento3/index.php/admin/

Comment: I have added , then I get The requested URL /magento3/admin/admin/index/index/key/60c13d3d1ef4c0906b335b30c34ae42c2aa2370fcc5e664547de153ec1287916/ was not found on this server.

Comment: Basically you need to add rewritebase in your htaccess as the magento folder is not directly inside your apache root but its inside a folder called magento3. Please check this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/704102/how-does-rewritebase-work-in-htaccess. SO in your case it will be rewritebase /magneto3/. Make sure mod rewrites is enabled and allowoverride in your virtual-host is set to all instead of none