# Is this RewriteRule reduntant?

Tags: .htaccess

I found a `.htaccess` file in the `/htdocs/wordpress/` folder.

The url `www.example.com` points to the `/htdocs` directory.

Wordpress is called by `www.example.com/wordpress`

This is the content of the `.htaccess`:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /wordpress/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /wordpress/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

I found in https://stackoverflow.com/a/27913187/2311074 that

> Using RewriteBase like this...
>
> ```
> RewriteBase /folder/
> RewriteRule a\.html b.html
> ```
>
> is essentially the same as...
>
> ```
> RewriteRule a\.html /folder/b.html
> ```
>
> But when the .htaccess file is inside /folder/ then this also points to the same target:
>
> ```
> RewriteRule a\.html b.html
> ```

So I guess its not needed? Further, I don't see what

```
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
```

is doing. Where is it redirecting to? Anyway, everything will be redirected in the end to

```
RewriteRule . /wordpress/index.php [L]
```

so the first RewriteRule is rewritten anyway, right?

Is the above `.htaccess` file equivalent to this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /wordpress/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I am correct this rule is preventing direct access to index.php here '-' will do 403 forbidden access when a user attempt direct access to index.php.

```
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
```