# Are my Apache2 RewriteEngine On and AllowOverride All changes secure?

Tags: php, apache2, xenforo

I made some changes to my website configuration in order to get friendly urls working on Xenforo2 running on Apache2.

a) I turned RewriteEngine "On" in my .htaccess file

b) I modified RewriteBase  to '/' in my .htaccess file

c) I changed AllowOverride from "None" to "All" in the  section of my Apache2 configuration.

Do any of these changes open me up to security problems down the line?
My apache2 version is 2.4.25 (Debian)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Those 3 additions/modifications to your `.htaccess` file and apache config pose no direct security risk.

- Turning on `RewriteEngine` is simply that. Allowing htaccess to make redirects etc.
- Changing the `RewriteBase` simply sets the base url that redirects will happen from. More information can be found here: [How does RewriteBase work in .htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/704102/how-does-rewritebase-work-in-htaccess/704171#704171)
- Setting `AllowOverride` from `None` to `All` in your apache configuration allows your `.htaccess` file to work at all. If it was set to `None`, your `.htaccess` would not work, as htaccess is an override of your apache config.