# bottle + CGI always matches / route

Tags: python, apache, routes, cgi, bottle

I can't get bottle to match any other route than "/" when deploying in a CGI environment. (I'm stuck with the hosting provider, FastCGI or WSGI are not on offer, unfortunately).

Bottle lives in a subdirectory `lib` - I have dropped the bottle.py from bottle-0.12.18.tar.gz there.

Python is either 3.5.3 (provider) or 3.8.2 (localhost)

I have the following in a `.htaccess`

```
Options +ExecCGI
AddHandler cgi-script .py

Options -Indexes

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteRule ^static\/ - [L]  
  RewriteRule .* application.py [L]
</IfModule>
```

and the following `application.py`

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

#setup lib path
import os
import os.path
import sys
if 'SCRIPT_NAME' in os.environ:
    MY_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(os.environ['SCRIPT_FILENAME']))
else:
    MY_DIR = os.environ['PWD']    
sys.path.append(os.path.join(MY_DIR,'lib'))


from bottle import Bottle

app = Bottle()

@app.route('/test')
def test():
    return '<b>matched @app.route("/test") - Testing: One, Two</b>!'

@app.route('/')
def index():
    r = ""
    for p in os.environ.keys():
        r += "{0} : {1}\n".format(p,os.environ[p])
    return '<b>matched @app.route("/")</b>\n<pre>'+r+'</pre>'

app.run(server='cgi')
```

This *always* return the output from `index()`, no matter what URL I request.

From the output

```
matched @app.route("/")

APP_ENGINE : phpcgi
APP_ENGINE_VERSION : 7.3
AUTH_TYPE : Basic
CFG_CLUSTER : cluster003
DOCUMENT_ROOT : /home/somethinguxiz/www-dev
ENVIRONMENT : production
GATEWAY_INTERFACE : CGI/1.1
HOME : /homez.907/somethinguxiz
HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING : gzip, deflate, br
HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE : en,de-DE;q=0.7,de;q=0.3
HTTP_ACCEPT : text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
HTTP_DNT : 1
HTTP_FORWARDED : for=51.xxx.xxx.xxx; proto=https; host=dev.something.else
HTTP_HOST : dev.something.else
HTTP_REMOTE_IP : 90.xxx.xxx.xxx
HTTPS : on
HTTP_UPGRADE_INSECURE_REQUESTS : 1
HTTP_USER_AGENT : Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:74.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/74.0
HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR : 90.xxx.xxx.xxx
HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PORT : 443
HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO : https
HTTP_X_PREDICTOR : 1
HTTP_X_REMOTE_IP : 51.xxx.xxx.xxx
HTTP_X_REMOTE_PORT : 64440
HTTP_X_REMOTE_PROTO : https
PATH : /usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin
PHP_VER : 5_TEST
PWD : /homez.907/somethinguxiz/www-dev
QUERY_STRING : 
REDIRECT_STATUS : 200
REDIRECT_URL : /test
REGISTER_GLOBALS : 0
REMOTE_ADDR : 90.xxx.xxx.xxx
REMOTE_PORT : 17926
REMOTE_USER : csomething
REQUEST_METHOD : GET
REQUEST_URI : /test
SCRIPT_FILENAME : /home/somethinguxiz/www-dev/application.py
SCRIPT_NAME : /application.py
SCRIPT_URI : https://dev.something.else:443/test
SCRIPT_URL : /test
SERVER_ADDR : 51.xxx.xxx.xxx
SERVER_ADMIN : postmaster@dev.something.else
SERVER_NAME : dev.something.else
SERVER_PORT : 443
SERVER_PROTOCOL : HTTP/1.1
SERVER_SIGNATURE : 
SERVER_SOFTWARE : Apache
UID : somethinguxiz
```

I.e. the script *does* see the `REQUEST_URI` yet it does not fire `test()` but `index()`!?

Any ideas, pointers?

EDIT:
unless it is removed somewhere, `PATH_INFO` is missing in the above list although it should be there if I understand the CGI specs correctly. It's also what bottle uses in its match() method. It falls back to `/` if not present (which explains that always `index()` is called.

EDIT: move solution text to answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`PATH_INFO` is only set if the path goes beyond the cgi script. While my original intent was to have that invisible I have made peace with having an application name here. Plus, there is a difference in having `[L]` in the rewrite rule compared to `[END]`.

Thus I settled with the following `.htaccess`:

```
Options +ExecCGI                                                                                                                     
AddHandler cgi-script .py                                                                                                            
AcceptPathInfo on                                                                                                                    

Options -Indexes                                                                                                                     

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>                                                                                                             
    RewriteEngine On                                                                                                                 
    RewriteOptions IgnoreInherit                                                                                                     
    RewriteBase /                                                                                                              
    RewriteRule ^demo\/(static\/.*)$ $1 [END]                                                                                        
    RewriteRule ^demo(/.*)$ application.py$1 [END]                                                                                   
    RewriteRule ^demo$ application.py [END]                                                                                           
    RewriteRule !^demo$ demo [R,END]                                                                                                  
</IfModule>
```

It allows to serve static content from httpd while application logic is in `application.py` - hidden as `demo`. Anything else redirects to the front door.

Application is at `.../demo`,
Pages within the application are at `.../demo/path/to/page`, and
Ressources served by httpd are at `.../demo/static/path/to/ressource`

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem too, and found a solution that let me completely eliminate any path leftovers for the script itself. The following Apache Rewrite directives in the .htaccess file in the CGI script's directory did the trick:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteBase /

  RewriteRule ^$ script.py                # (1)
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f     # (2)
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d     # (3)
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ script.py/$1 [QSA,L] # (4)
</IfModule>
```

Explanations of the numbered lines:

1. The first RewriteRule sends any *index* requests (such as for https://www.example.com with or without the trailing slash) directly to the script. This takes care of one half of my needs: to have the "front door" be handled by my script as well. *If you have a static index page, leave this Rule out.*
2. This Condition takes care of static files: if it already exists at the request location, the next rewrite is skipped. Since the next Rule is how the script ever sees non-index requests, this makes Apache serve it directly instead of sending it to the script. *If you have no static files to serve, or want the application's own logic to serve static files, leave this Condition out.*
3. Same as (2) but for directories.
4. The other half of the solution. This rewrites any requests that aren't already served by the previous rules: anything like `/<non-empty-request>` will run as if it was `/script.py/<non-empty-request>`.

Thus, 1st line's Rule sending `https://www.example.com` to my script lets its `@app.route('/')` handler do its job properly regardless of static index files, and the 4th line's Rule makes sure all other requests for non-static files are properly fed to the script, and are handled by all other registered route handlers.

As a side note, that `RewriteBase /` isn't strictly necessary, but I like to have that default made explicit. See [this answer to How does RewriteBase work in .htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27913187/480642) for a thorough breakdown of `RewriteBase` and what it's good for.