# How to redirect page and url from subfolders?

Tags: php

My pages (**index.php** and **view-contract.php**) were in the root directory before, but then I moved these pages to the **"account"** folder. Before the pages were moved my `RewriteRule` was working but now it's not. I tried some of the subfolders redirection rules but they didn't work.

Thanks in advance.

**URL in account/index.php**

```
<a href="view-contract/'.$row['contractSlug'].'">'.$row['contractName'].'</a>
```

**.htaccess**

```
Options -Indexes -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /dashboard/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f [NC]

RewriteRule ^view-contract/([\w-]+)/?$ view-contract.php?contractID=$1 [QSA,L,NC]
```

Comment: You are rewriting to `view-contract.php` – where is the `account` folder in that path …?

Comment: I tried to put before view-contract.php (`account/view-contract.php`) but it didn't work.

Comment: probably you need to change `RewriteBase /dashboard/` to `RewriteBase /account/` if your aim is `/account/view-contract.php`. Also here is no rule for `index.php` at all. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/704102/how-does-rewritebase-work-in-htaccess

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes changes made to the `.htaccess` file do not take effect until you clear the browser history. **First, clear your browser history.**

And again show the subdirectory/folder path in the RewritRule:

```
RewriteRule ^account/view-contract/([\w-]+)/?$ account/view-contract.php?contractID=$1 [QSA,L,NC]
```

Comment: Clearing browser history really worked. That's the only problem. Thank you.