# Redirect all subpages to main page using htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to redirect all subpages to main page. I tried with code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .+ http://www.example.com [r=301,nc,l]
```

All subpages are redirected except these that include question mark, for example, `http://www.example.com/?123` is not redirected. How to modify my code to redirect also those URLs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to redirect any non-empty URL-path OR the homepage (empty URL-path) with a query string. You should also *remove* the query string as part of the redirect (your rule currently preserves the query string from the initial request).

For example, try the following instead:

```
# Redirect everything to the homepage (same domain)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/. [OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} .
RewriteRule ^ http://www.example.com/ [QSD,R=301,L]
```

The above states... for all URL-paths where the URL-path consists of at least one character (after the initial slash) OR contains a query string then redirect to the root.

The `QSD` flag discards the original query string from the request.

The `NC` flag on the rule is superfluous, since you aren't matching specific letters anyway.

*Aside:* However, I would question the motives for doing something like this. Search engines (Google) will see mass redirects to the homepage as soft-404s, so there is no SEO benefit in doing this and it can often be confusing for users if they are following a link that previously existed. A meaningful 404 response is usually the preferred option in this scenario.

---

**UPDATE:**

> If i would like to use this code also to redirect to other domain what should i change or add to redirect also main page?

Assuming the other domain also points to a different server then you just need to remove the two *conditions* on the above rule to redirect *everything* and remove the query string.

For example:

```
# Redirect everything to the homepage on an external domain
RewriteRule ^ http://www.example.com/ [QSD,R=301,L]
```

Comment: your code works fine. If i would like to use this code also to redirect to _other_ domain what should i change or add to redirect also main page?

Comment: @Marian You basically just need to remove the two _conditions_. I've updated my answer.

Comment: update works fine, i tried myself to modify first line deleting /. it also works but removing 2 first lines is easier. I have always used before the rules RewriteEngine On and RewriteBase / lines. I put your code and forgot to add those 2 lines but rewrites work fine. Is it not necessary to use them?

Comment: @Marian "modify first line deleting /. it also works" - If you only removed the first _condition_ then it would only redirect URLs with a query string (ie. with a question mark followed by something). It wouldn't redirect `http://www.example.com/foo` for instance. The `RewriteBase` directive is certainly not required here (there are no relative substitutions).  However, the `RewriteEngine On` directive is generally required, unless it has already been enabled in a parent config (the default is `Off`).

Comment: I did not remove the first condition, only /. from first condition so left RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^ [OR]. Without RewriteEngine On works for me, so i guess it is enabled, but maybe it is better to add this directive.

Comment: @Marian Ah I see, yes that would have worked, but it just makes the 2nd condition redundant, since it would always be successful. Yes, you should always have an instance of `RewriteEngine On` in the `.htaccess` file (preferably at the top, for readability).

Comment: Just one more question, when rule RewriteBase / should be used?

Comment: @Marian The `RewriteBase` directive sets (overrides) the URL-path that is prefixed to **relative** _substitution_ strings. (The _substitution_ string is the 2nd arg to the `RewriteRule` directive.) That is all it does. It is often not required (despite what the [Apache docs](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritebase) state). In fact, `RewriteBase /` is rarely required. `RewriteBase` seems to cause a lot of confusion, but it's actually quite simple. See the following question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/704102/how-does-rewritebase-work-in-htaccess

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it works in my system.

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/ [L,R=301]
```

Comment: (Why would you need to do something like this in your "ERP system"?) However, the directive you've posted cannot possibly "work" as written - it would create an endless redirect loop and it would fail to remove the query string as stated in the question.

Comment: It redirects users from another, not working yet server. Maybe You may be right but it works great.

Comment: Ok, but the question would seem to be about redirecting to the _same_ domain.

Comment: @DamianChlebica your code doesn't work properly. If i use it to _same_ domain it doesn't work at all: www.example.com/?1 is still www.example.com/?1 , if you use it to _other_ domain www.example1.com/?1 redirects to www.example2.com/?1

Comment: so, how to fix it? RewriteCond   %{HTTP_HOST} ^prod\.ab-cb\.name\.pl$ [NC]
RewriteRule   ^(.*)$ http://ab-cb.net/ [L,R=301]