# Routing in PHP using .htaccess and Apache runs into "NOT FOUND"

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, web, routes

I am trying to create a PHP router for a website with 2 pages on an Apache Server. But I keep running into `NOT FOUND The requested URL was not found on this server`. Below is my code structure.

Folder Structure

```
/var/www/html/project_folder
| .htaccess
| app
    | index.php
    | page1.php
    | page2.php
    | 404.php
```

index.php

```php
<?php

$request_uri = explode('/', parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']));
$requested_page = $request_uri[2];

if ($requested_page === '' || $requested_page === 'page1') {
   $route = '/page1.php';} 
elseif ($requested_page === 'page2') {
   $route = '/page2.php';
} else {    
   $route = '/404.php'; 
}

require __DIR__ . $route;
```

page1.php / page2.php - similar content

```
<?php 
echo '<h1>Page No: 1</h1>';
```

.htaccess

```
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /app/
  RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteRule . /project_folder/app/index.php [L,QSA]
```

When I run the same setup on localhost `localhost/project_folder/app` and `localhost/project_folder/app/page2`, the pages are rendered.
However, on the server:

1. When I try the default path `www.myWebPageName.com/app/`, page1 is rendered successfully
2. When I try on the servers using `www.myWebPageName.com/app/page1`, I get `NOT FOUND`

Answer (score 0):

You wouldn't need to include `/project_folder/app/` in the `RewriteRule` since you are already using a `RewriteBase`.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /app/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule . index.php [L,QSA]
```

The way you have it written is the same as saying (without the RewriteBase):

`RewriteRule . /app/project_folder/app/index.php [L,QSA]`

The top answer here gives a pretty good explanation of what you're trying to achieve: [How does RewriteBase work in .htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/704102/how-does-rewritebase-work-in-htaccess)